# UI Scroll like iPhone HTML 5

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using `jQuery`, `HTML 5` ,and `CSS 3`.

The requirement is I need to implement exactly like http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/pull-to-refresh/ for showing list like iPhone.

How do I we create this scrollable content with that stylish scroll bar. Is there any `jQuery` plugin & UI code available?

I need the content to be fetched by `ajax` when user scroll down and there is no data.

Comment: You might want to try jquerymobile http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/intro/

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there!  iScroll4 is the library that achieves the demo you have come across and it plays nicely with jQuery.  It isn't jQuery in itself, but it's small, efficient and IMHO very good!

http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Pay careful attention to the notes on the `refresh()` method (not 'pull to refresh' which is different) - you'll need to do that after requesting AJAX content. This is easily missed but if implemented correctly, works very well.